# Unity3D Cubemap Importer class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to reimport a (legacy) Cubemap asset in Unity 2019 using the legacy `AssetImporter` class

I incorrectly assumed, considering the `Cubemap` class derives from the `Texture` class that I could cast to `TextureImporter`. Unfortunately this does not seem to be the case and doing so throws an `InvalidCastException`

The code in question, where `source` is of type `Cubemap`:

```
string path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(source);
importer = (TextureImporter) AssetImporter.GetAtPath(path);
```

All I need to do with the importer is change the `isReadable` property. There's no reference in the documentation to a `"CubemapImporter"` that I could cast to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be the right way to do it, but it sure works and I don't see an alternative.
Hope this helps someone:

```
string path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(source);

string windowsPath = HelperFunctions.EditorAssetPathToWindowsAssetPath(path);

string content = File.ReadAllText(windowsPath);

content = content.Replace("m_IsReadable: 0", "m_IsReadable: 1");

File.Delete(windowsPath);

File.WriteAllText(windowsPath, content);

AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(path);
```

All that `EditorAssetPathToWindowsAssetPath` does is convert the path given by `GetAssetPath` to a Windows path that can be used by `System.IO`

You can replicate this functionality with `Application.dataPath`